# Expectation of random variable conditioned on sigma-algebra of another random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, density-function

If $X, Y \sim f(x,y)$ are jointly absolutely-continuous and if $\mathcal{G} = \sigma(Y)$, then

$$E[X | Y] = \frac{\int xf(x, Y) dx}{\int f(x, Y) dx}.$$

I encountered the above in lecture notes on [Conditional Expection](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Fall10/sta205/lec/topics/rn.pdf) as I was looking for resources for learning probability theory and was wondering if there was a proof of this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What you wrote is not quite right. What you have is actually a version of $E(X \mid Y = y).$

Comment: Ah yes, you're right; I have fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\nu$ denote the probability density function of $Y$, that is
$$
\nu(y)=\int f(x,y)\,dx,
$$
and let
$$
p(x,y)=\frac{f(x,y)}{\nu(y)}1_{\{\nu(y)\neq0\}}\quad\textrm{and}\quad\varphi(y)=\int xp(x,y)\,dx.
$$

Let $h$ be a nonnegative measurable map. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
E[Xh(Y)]&=\int xh(y)f(x,y)\,dx\,dy=\int xh(y)p(x,y)\nu(y)\,dx\,dy\\
&=\int h(y)\nu(y)\left(\int xp(x,y)\,dx\right)\,dy\\
&=\int h(y)\nu(y)\varphi(y)\,dy\\
&=E[\varphi(Y)h(Y)].
\end{align*}
$$

Therefore, almost surely,
$$
E[X\vert Y]=\varphi(Y)=\int xp(x,Y)\,dx=\frac{\int xf(x,Y)\,dx}{\int f(x,Y)\,dx}1_{\{\int f(x,Y)\,dx\neq0\}}.
$$